# Why does Selenium Webdriver opens new window for every time run the script and how to fix it?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run following code. But everytime I run a new chrome window opens. How to fix this problem. Also the new chrome instance that open are *not logged in* so I am unable to use the extension that i have already installed. Any way to fix this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

I have provided screenshot for the same:

[image: new chrome instances]

Code trials:

```
package com.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

[image: base instance]
.
.
[image: new instance not logged in]

Comment: This is the expected behavior, there is nothing to fix. For loading extensions you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34222412/5168011)

Comment: @Guy   ok..thanks..is there any alternative to firebug/firepath

Comment: In Chrome you have developer tools F12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute your code each time a new *ChromeDriver* instance is created which spawns a new *Chrome Browser* session. This functionality is *as per design*.

A better approach would be to invoke **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy both the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* instances gracefully after each run of *Test Execution*. You can find a detailed [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790).

Though that would solve the issue of multiple *Chrome Browser* windows still you won't be *logged in* within your new session. To get logged in  you need to use a specific *Chrome Profile* and store the *cookies* and reuse them later. You will find a detailed discussion on how to *create and open a new Chrome Profile* in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195).

To use the *extension* that you have installed you need to pack/unpack them and use `ChromeOptions` class.

---

### [Chrome Extensions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions)

Chrome extensions can be either packed or unpacked.  Packed extensions are a single file with a .crx extension.  Unpacked extensions are a directory containing the extension, including a `manifest.json` file.

To pack an unpacked extension, use the Pack button in `chrome://extensions` or use Chrome (Windows example):

```
chrome.exe --pack-extension=C:\path\to\unpacked\extension --pack-extension-key=C:\myext.pem
```

See the [extensions docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting) for other ways to do this that are more automation friendly.  To unpack a packed extension, just unzip the file (you may need to rename the file from `.crx` to `.zip` for your zip utility to recognize it).

### Using extensions through ChromeDriver

- Packed (.crx file):

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```
- Unpacked (directory):

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  ```

Comment: hi  this is loading only one extension.. how to add multiple file path..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the window to close at the end you can call

`driver.Quit();`

and that should close it and clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Selnium 4 Java jars and Selenium server jar resolved my issue of extra Chrome browser window

https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/